# How to create a ZoneId given custom ZoneRules

Tags: java, time

Want to be able to create custom timezones offset from a particular zone (but observing daylight savings transitions).  For example would like to be able to indicate:

```
ZoneId.of("America/New_York+7")
```

The above zone would observe either EST or EDT, depending on daylight savings time + 7 hours.  The application for this relates to FX markets start / end of day (which is 5pm New York time).

The above offset format is disallowed in ZoneId, as ZoneId only allows for offsets from UTC.

I had implemented a class which generates custom `ZoneRules`, but then the `ZoneRegion` constructor, a subclass of ZoneId is not public.  ZoneRegion has the following, unavailable constructor:

```
ZoneRegion(String name, ZoneRules rules)
```

So the question is, short of not using the java.time library, is there any way to get the behavior of a custom zone with DST rules?   Alternatively, does someone know how this would be done using the Joda date/time library?

**Addendum**

Note that one cannot create subclasses of ZoneId due to the following code in ZoneId (which frankly, seems like a very bad idea unless there is some security reason which I cannot fathom):

```
/**
 * Constructor only accessible within the package.
 */
ZoneId() {
    if (getClass() != ZoneOffset.class && getClass() != ZoneRegion.class) {
        throw new AssertionError("Invalid subclass");
    }
}
```

Comment: Create your own subclass of `ZoneId` and call its `of` method.

Comment: I started down that path at first but then discovered that they had put in code into the base class to disallow custom subclasses.  See above